# How to describe the family $\tau$ of all open sets of $(\mathbb R^2,\delta)$

Tags: metric-spaces

> **Ex. 1.2.65.** Let $d$ be the Euclidean metric on $\Bbb R^2$. Define
>   $$\delta(p,q):=\begin{cases}
> d(p,0)+d(q,0), & p\ne q \\
> 0, & p = q,
> \end{cases}$$
>   for $p, q \in \Bbb R^2$. Show that $\delta$ is a metric on $\Bbb R^2$. What are $B_\delta(0,\varepsilon)$ for $\varepsilon > 0$? Can you describe the $\delta$-open sets?

I've shown for $\varepsilon>0,~p\in\mathbb R^2$
$$B_\delta(p,\varepsilon)=\begin{cases}
\{ p \} & \text{if }p\ne0,\; d(p,0)\ge\varepsilon\\
B_d(0,\varepsilon-d(p,0))\cup\{p\} & \text{if }p\ne0,\;d(p,0)<\varepsilon\\
B_d(0,\varepsilon) & \text{if }p=0
\end{cases}$$

Thus all the subset of $\mathbb R^2$ not containning $0$ is an open set and so do each open ball of $(\mathbb R^2,d)$ centered at the origin.

Is it correct to describe the family $\tau$ of all open sets of $(\mathbb R^2,\delta)$ as [*assuming $B_\delta(0,0)=\emptyset$*]
$$\tau=\{X\cup B_d(0,\varepsilon):\varepsilon\ge 0, \,0\notin X\subset\mathbb R^2\}$$ 
Text: [Topology of Metric Spaces - S. Kumaresan](http://books.google.co.in/books/about/Topology_of_Metric_Spaces.html?id=ehZ_LRmG3JMC&redir_esc=y)

Comment: Yes, that is correct.

Comment: $B(p, \varepsilon)$ should only really be defined for $\varepsilon > 0$, so you can throw that problem away immediately. Otherwise, yes, you're right. All $\delta$-open balls are a singleton set (but not $\{0\}$), or a Euclidean open ball around zero, or a union of the two. So any set that doesn't contain zero is open; and any set that contains zero and a small Euclidean open ball around it is open. A non-open set would be, for example, $\{(x,y) : y \leq x^2\}$.

Comment: @Billy Why should $B(p, \varepsilon)$ only be defined for strictly positive $\varepsilon$? If you go by the most basic definition,
$$
B(p, \varepsilon) = \{x \: |\: d(x, p) < \varepsilon\}
$$
then setting $\varepsilon$ to be zero or even negative would make perfect sense. The result would just be the empty set.

Answer (score 2):

The solution was confirmed to be correct in the comments.  I'll add two remarks:

1. I think that $X\subseteq \mathbb R^2\setminus\{0\}$ is easier to understand (and is more standard) than $0\notin X\subset \mathbb R^2$.
2. The metric  happens to be an *ultrametric*: it satisfies $d(p,q)\le \max(d(p,r), d(q,r))$ for all $p,q,r$.